# PyQT Navigation between layouts

Tags: python, pyqt5

Below is my application code which allows you to switch between windows. The menu has two options programmed such as 'Detail Report' and 'All companies' and now after loading the layout I do not know how I can put the button in these 2 views that would allow you to change the view from Detail Report to All Companies and vice versa. Can you help me :) ?

```
class App(QMainWindow):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.dashboardView = DashboardWindow()
    self.detailView = RaportWindow()
    self.infoView = InfoWindow()
    self.init_ui()
    self.show()

def init_ui(self):

    main_menu = self.menuBar()
    dashboard = main_menu.addMenu('Dashboard')

    dashboard.addAction(QAction('Detail Raport', self))
    dashboard.addAction(QAction('All companies', self))
    dashboard.triggered.connect(self.change_view)
    self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
    self.show()


def change_view(self, q):
    if q.text() == 'Detail Raport':
        self.detailView.detailRaport(self)
        self.show()
    if q.text() == 'All companies':
        self.dashboardView.setupUIdashboard(self)
        self.show()


class RaportWindow(object):
def detailRaport(self, MainWindow):
    self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
    grid = QGridLayout()
    ...
    self.centralwidget.setLayout(grid)
    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

class DashboardWindow(object):
def setupUIdashboard(self, MainWindow):
    self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
    grid = QGridLayout()
    .....

    self.centralwidget.setLayout(grid)
    scrollArea = QScrollArea()
    scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
    scrollArea.setWidget(self.centralwidget)
    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(scrollArea)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First DashboardWindow and RaportWindow are not widgets, they are classes that fill widgets that you have probably created using Qt Designer, what you must do is create a class that inherits from a widget and uses the previous classes to fill it.

Going to the point, you must use `QStackedWidget` to be able to exchange widgets.

```
class App(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.init_ui()
        self.show()

    def init_ui(self):
        main_menu = self.menuBar()
        dashboard = main_menu.addMenu('Dashboard')
        dashboard.addAction(QAction('Detail Raport', self))
        dashboard.addAction(QAction('All companies', self))
        dashboard.triggered.connect(self.change_view)

        self.dashboardView = Dashboard()
        self.detailView = Raport()

        self.stacked = QStackedWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.stacked)
        self.stacked.addWidget(self.detailView)
        self.stacked.addWidget(self.dashboardView)

    def change_view(self, q):
        if q.text() == 'Detail Raport':
            self.stacked.setCurrentWidget(self.detailView)
        elif q.text() == 'All companies':
            self.stacked.setCurrentWidget(self.dashboardView)

class RaportWindow(object):
    def detailRaport(self, MainWindow):
        ...

class DashboardWindow(object):
    def setupUIdashboard(self, MainWindow):
        ...

class Dashboard(QMainWindow, DashboardWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Dashboard, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUIdashboard(self)

class Raport(QMainWindow, RaportWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Raport, self).__init__(parent)
        self.detailRaport(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = App()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Ok it's working so how can i add method in RaportWindow class (And button in detailRaport) that can me allow to change view to DashBoard ? https://pastebin.com/CwMHcBVs

Comment: @vsystem That connection do it in App since both exist in that scope, if my answer I help you do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it review the [tour], that is the best way to thank. ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, I probably did not understand this advice well. Could you tell me exactly how I should put the button?

Answer (score 0):

I think that this solution can be usefull

```
class App(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(0, 30, 500, 500)
        self.init_ui()
        self.show()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.central_widget = QStackedWidget()

        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)

        self.report_screen = ReportWindow(self)
        self.company_screen = CompanyWindow(self)

        self.central_widget.addWidget(self.report_screen)
        self.central_widget.addWidget(self.company_screen)

        self.central_widget.setCurrentWidget(self.report_screen)

        self.report_screen.clicked.connect(lambda: 
        self.central_widget.setCurrentWidget(self.company_screen))
        self.company_screen.clicked.connect(lambda: 
        self.central_widget.setCurrentWidget(self.report_screen))


class Report(object):
    clicked = pyqtSignal()

    def detail_report(self):
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.button = QPushButton('test1')
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.clicked.emit)


class ReportWindow(QWidget, Report):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ReportWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.detail_report()


class Company(object):
    clicked = pyqtSignal()

    def list_companies(self):
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.button = QPushButton('test2')
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.clicked.emit)


class CompanyWindow(QWidget, Company):
    clicked = pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CompanyWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.list_companies()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = App()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```